# What is the keyboard shortcut to assign a keyboard shortcut to a menu command?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

When changing a keyboard shortcut in Word, I don't always know how the associated command is called, so it's cumbersome to search for it in the customize ribbon -> keyboard shortcuts command list.

I know there's a keyboard shortcut that can be pressed, the mouse cursor will transform into the "command" key `⌘` symbol.
After that, if another keyboard shortcut is pressed, such as `ctrl+N`, the menu interface to change the associated command (in this case: "New Document") will open automatically.

I've used that method many times, but now I forgot the shortcut. A web search didn't help.
How's that keyboard shortcut ?

Comment: It is not hard to find the keyboard shortcuts  (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2)   but it has proven for me to be faster overall (vastly faster if I forget something) just to use the menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Word for Windows: `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Numeric Keypad "+"`

My preference, though, is to assign them through the Customize the Keyboard button on the Customize the Ribbon dialog. Here is my article on [Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts in Word 2007-2019](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330).

See my other article on [creating a list of keyboard shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/create-a-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft/7952be51-6a8e-4382-994c-e6632ba4cf35?tm=1589698042191) (I recommend to pdf).